# Python error, 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable'

Tags: python

Here is the code that python is saying that caused the error.
This is when i define it

```
   *def searchCounty(newlist):
        whatCounty = input("Which county are you looking for?\n")
        **for eachItem in newlist:**
                if whatCounty in eachItem[1]:
                    print("Town:", eachItem[0], ", County:", eachItem[1], ", Population:", eachItem[2], ", Area:", eachItem[3])*
```

and this is where i call it back.

```
allTowns = readsFile()
townsList = splitFile(allTowns)
userChoice = displayMenu()
if userChoice == "a":
    searchTown(townsList)    #calls function using the townsList created 3 lines above
elif userChoice == "b":
    **searchCounty(townsList)**
elif userChoice == "q":
    print("Goodbye!")
else:
    print("Invalid input please enter a, b or q")
```

Please help.The lines with 2 asterisks are the ones causing the error.And the two variables ( allTowns and townsList) print out a bunch of lists that have a mixture of strings and numbers , but when the second one is executed it says none on screen.I am guessing split file splits up the the big list into many lists, as that is what allTowns is initially, as i honestly dont know for sure what it does.

Comment: Which line is raising the error?

Comment: Are you sure that `splitFile` is returning what it is supposed to return?

Comment: Most likely, either `newlist` or `eachItem[1]` is `None`, and you can't iterate over it.

Comment: Having the actual stackdump with the line numbers would likely help, here.

Comment: I couldnt put all of the code but  i think it is just the lines with asterisks causing the problems, as it worked fine up to this point

Answer (score 0):

Based off what you've said, one of these functions is causing an issue:

```
allTowns = readsFile()
townsList = splitFile(allTowns)
```

as townsList is defined to None when you attempt to iterate through it inside of `searchCounty()`.

Here's what's essentially happening (as done in the python shell):

```
>>> for i in None:
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

so you should check that allTowns is right as well as townsList.

Comment: `print()` it before trying to iterate over it so you can see what it is.

Comment: allTown and townsList both print out stuff, but when i print townsList it says none at the end, which maybe the problem, any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Could you paste what all they actually print (as well as what splitFile does) in your question? Just saying "they print stuff" doesn't really allow us to debug why it might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in this line of code:

```
 if whatCounty in eachItem[1]:
```

you should be comparing for equality there rather than containment.

```
 if whatCounty == eachItem[1]:
```

should give you the comparison you are trying to accomplish.